# Extjs calendarpanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm developing application on ExtJs 4
I'm using MVC architecture.
In native examples of Extjs there is calendar from Extensible Calendar.
I'm trying use this example in my application, whithout MVC it works well,
how can use this example in my application?
Please help me!
this is my view

```
    Ext.define('Module.notification.reminder.view.Calendar', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.calendartry',
    requires: [
        'Ext.Viewport',
        'Ext.layout.container.Border',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Rest',
        'Ext.picker.Date',
        'Ext.calendar.util.Date',
        'Ext.calendar.CalendarPanel',
        'Ext.calendar.data.MemoryCalendarStore',
        'Ext.calendar.data.MemoryEventStore',
        'Ext.calendar.data.Events',
        'Ext.calendar.data.Calendars',
        'Ext.calendar.form.EventWindow'
    ],
    autoShow: false,
    layout: 'fit',
    Store: ['Ext.calendar.data.Events'],
    initComponent: function () {



        this.items = [{
                xtype: 'calendarpanel',
                eventStore: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {}),
                calendarStore: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {}),
                title: 'Calendar',
                name: 'eLeave-calendar',
                height: 500,
                width: 500
            }];
        Ext.calendar.data.CalendarModel.reconfigure();
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. What have you tried, which errorneous behaviour did it result in?

Comment: I want to implement Extensible calendar in MVC

Comment: I'm getting an error ```TypeError: b.getSelectionModel is not a function```

Comment: help please with my error

Comment: Since this is a closed-source component used by no more than a few hundred people worldwide, the error should be reported to the Ext.ensible support.

Comment: I have found the issue

Answer (score -1):

Use the xtpe :'datefield' inside the panel or container

```
items: [{
xtype: 'datefield',name: 'startPeriod',
fieldLabel: 'Start Period',
emptyText: 'Select Period',allowBlank: false
},                                   
{
xtype: 'datefield',name: 'endPeriod',
fieldLabel: 'End Period' 
emptyText: 'Select Period',allowBlank: false
}]
```

Comment: in wich part? can you explain